# hello guys I'm new to react I was trying to display my header component but it's not show

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import header from "./header";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My First React App</h1>

      <header />
      {/* tinder card */}
      {/* swipe  */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// header.js
import React from "react";
import "./header.css";

function header() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <h2>I am the header</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components must have an initial capital letter, since lower-case names are considered to be HTML tags by React (or JSX in particular) ([and `<header>` is one, anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header)).

Rename `header` to `Header`:

```
export default function Header() {
  // ...
}
```

and import and use it in the capitalized form too:

```
import Header from "./header";
// ...
<Header />
```